# Disposing of all registered services?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to dependency injection and Unity and I've come up with a way to call the `Dispose` method on all of my registered services.

Here's what I got so far. This is part of my `UnityResolver` class:

```
public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;
    private List<object> serviceList = new List<object>();

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceList.Add(container.Resolve(serviceType));
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            container.ResolveAll(serviceType).ToList().ForEach(x => serviceList.Add(x));
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
        var disposables = serviceList.Where(x => x is IDisposable).ToList();

        foreach (IDisposable service in disposables)
        {
            service.Dispose();
        }       
     }
}
```

It works so far, but is there a best (better) practice approach to doing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are resolving twice, what would happen if a service is registered as Transient (the default)?

Comment: Check this guy has two approaches https://florincoros.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/extending-unity-container-for-idisposable-instances-2nd-approach/

Comment: Seems like you are reinventing the wheel: [approach 1](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/12/Unity-IoC-lifetime-management-IDisposable-part1.aspx), [approach 2](https://florincoros.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/extending-unity-container-for-idisposable-instances-1st-approach/).

Comment: Thanks, I will look up these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

What I think would solve your problem is using a Child Container.

```
var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
// make use of the childContainer
// ..
childContainer.Dispose(); // this will dispose any (transient) services created in the lifetime of the Child Container
```